# Using year fixed effects on test set

Tags: r

I have a training set that consists of data from the 2000-2011 period, and  a test set that goes from 2012 to 2016 period. I ran a logit model with year fixed effects in the training set (for the 2000-2011 period) and I want to use the predicted values for the test set.

I am having some trouble adding the year fixed effects in the test set (for 2012-2016), as the model used in the training set used completely different years (2000-2011).

How can I adjust for this differences? Here is the problem I am facing. Any idea?

Training set model:

```
model.2 <- glm(MAKE ~ NAME + DIST + DIST2 + DIST3 + SEASON + 
           GRASS + COLD49 + WINDY + ALTITUDE + PRECIP -1, 
           family = "binomial"(link = logit), data = df.train)
```

Test set model:

```
df.test$model.2.predictions <- predict(model.2, newdata = df.test, 
                                   type = "response")

Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
factor SEASON has new levels 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016
```

Comment: just wondering, if you use season (with year's as levels), then you are trying to look at specific effect of each level to your response right? since those effects are factor-level specific (e.g., year A has x increase in probability relative to year B), how do you expect the model predict the effect of years, not included in the training? -- I'm just really curious. Would it be possible to have a training set that encompasses all years?

Comment: It is true. The coefficients for seasonal fixed effects were estimated for that particular season and it doesn't make sense to multiply these coefficients against the dummy variables of the new seasons (2012 - 2016). I need to come up with new estimates for the coefficients of the seasons 2012 - 2016. 

I cannot build a training set that encompasses all years.

Comment: Leave out the year variable or if a trend is supposed to be assumed, then model it as numeric.

Comment: @42- I take upon your suggestion and assume a linear trend. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is levels in the test set that never appeares in the train set. 
Try `model.2$xlevels$SEASON <- union(model.2$xlevels$SEASON, levels(df.test$SEASON))` before doing the prediction and after training the model.

Comment: I have tried your recommendation, but the same error message appears. Any idea as to why? Thanks.